# Outlook 2007 sending mail from Yahoo

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007

I recently added a Yahoo e mail account to my Outlook 20007. Now I have a g-mail and yahoo account on my Outlook. how do I send email from Yahoo if my g-mail is the default account?

Answer (score 1):

When you have multiple accounts set up, you can choose which account send from by enabling the <kbd>From</kbd> button.

1. Open a new message.
2. Go to the `Options` tab in the message's toolbar.
3. Click `Show From` to make sure it is enabled.

[image]

Now there should be an <kbd>From</kbd> to choose which account you want to send from.

[image]

*Note: I am not using your version of Outlook, so my instructions and images may not be exact.*